Ejecutar chunk de phyton en r markdown
Al ejecutar este codigo de python en un programa de r-markdown
import pandas as pd
import chainladder as cl
clrd = cl.load_sample('clrd')

Genera el siguiente error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "offsets.pyx", line 4855, in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.to_offset
ValueError: last element must be blank


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


File "C:..\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\period.py", line 1193, in dt64arr_to_periodarr
freq = Period._maybe_convert_freq(freq)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "period.pyx", line 1765, in pandas._libs.tslibs.period._Period._maybe_convert_freq


File "offsets.pyx", line 4954, in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.to_offset


ValueError: Invalid frequency: Y-DIC., failed to parse with error message: ValueError('last element must be blank')

El mismo codigo corre en el interprete de Python
